EF Core add migration converting sqlite integer to bit?
I recently updated an older project and needed to add a new data migration. However, when I generated the migration, I noticed that all existing boolean columns were changed from INTEGER to bit. This happened across both SQLite and SQL Server providers. Here's an example of the migration code:
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<bool>(
    name: "Enabled",
    table: "ServiceRequests",
    type: "bit",
    nullable: false,
    defaultValue: true,
    oldClrType: typeof(bool),
    oldType: "INTEGER");

My Confusion:

Why is this happening now? Previously, the columns were of type INTEGER. Now they’re being altered to bit.
Is this the correct behavior? I couldn’t any documentation about bit columns working properly in SQLite. All of the resources I found suggest that INTEGER should be used for booleans in SQLite, yet my migrations keep changing the type to bit.

What I Tried:

I double-checked my configuration to make sure I wasn’t accidentally pulling in SQL Server settings when running SQLite migrations.
I removed all SQL Server-related files and settings from the project to ensure that I was running only SQLite code.
I tried running a migration on both an empty database and a migration from the previous version, and everything works as expected: boolean columns are created as bit, and data works fine in both providers.

When I inspect the database using DataGrip, the boolean columns are detected as bit and function correctly. So it seems like everything is working, but I'm concerned that this behavior might be accidental or undocumented.
My Question:
Is this change expected in newer versions of the EF Core SQLite provider, or am I running into an undocumented feature/behavior? I'm worried that my current setup might be functioning by chance and could cause issues down the line.

Additional Details:
I ran the following command to generate the migration:
Add-Migration AddFakeDelayToResponses -Context MockDoorMainContext -OutputDir Migrations

I expected only the changes I made to be present in the migration, but instead, all boolean fields were being converted to the bit type, which doesn’t seem to be standard behavior for SQLite.

edited question for format nicer and clarify details abit
